# Create a Tree using JPA

Tags: java, database, jpa, tree

I am trying to create a tree using entities and JPA. I have a class with the following properties.

```
public class Dir
{

@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "dirId")
private Integer dirId;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="dirId", cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
private Dir parent;
...
```

A node knows who its parent is, and if it doesnt have a parent, it is the root. Thats how I can easily build a tree out of this. But...
I dont think the mapping is correct for this thought. I get the following error when I try to deploy:

```
An incompatible mapping has been encountered between [class com.dv.oa.model.entity.dir.Dir] and [class com.dv.oa.model.entity.dir.Dir]. This usually occurs when the cardinality of a mapping does not correspond with the cardinality of its backpointer.
```

It talks about the cardinality. But this doesnt make sense, a node can only have one parent. This is why I chose `@OneToOne`

Can anyone shed some light on this? I guess another way of asking this would be, how do you map an entity to another instance of itself?

EDIT

Here is my table structure:

```
mysql> describe dir;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| dirId        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| DTYPE        | varchar(31)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| dirName      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| companyOwner | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| userOwner    | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| parent       | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 6):

You're pointing to the wrong column for the owning side of the mapping. Also your relationship is not OneToOne because a single Parent can have many Children.

```
@Entity
public class Dir
{

  //This field is a table column
  //It uniquely identifies a row on the DIR table
  @Id
  private int dirId;

  //This field is a table column
  // It identifies the parent of the current row
  // It it will be written as the type of dirId
  // By default this relationship will be eagerly fetched
  // , which you may or may not want
  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
  private Dir parent;

  //This field is not a table column
  // It is a collection of those Dir rows that have this row as a parent. 
  // This is the other side of the relationship defined by the parent field.
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
  private Set<Dir> children;
}
```

Comment: Interesting, this make sense. Will I also need a getter/setter for the children column?

Comment: Not necessarily. (You'll have to think through which side should own this relationship, how saves should cascade, Lazy fetching, updating, and refreshing, what you want to expose from the JPA model to the rest of your Java code, etc.). Depending on your JPA implementation, the child side is not necessarily required strictly... the key is the ManyToOne - OneToMany cardinality.

Comment: I have been trying this, but still keep on getting the same error. Not sure why that might be

Comment: What does your table structure look like?

Comment: I see there are other fields (companyOwner, userOwner) that appear to be relationships, are either of these mapped to a Dir entity accidentally? Also looking for anything else that might be an issue, I see you have a discriminator column (DTYPE) do any of the child classes define improper relationships?

Comment: userOwner is a object called User. In the User class, there is a relationship with a subclass of Dir. Same thing with companyOwner. Could this cause an issue? Im looking into the sub classes now

Comment: Maybe? I would look at all of your relationships, check the cardinality of them (ManyToOne/OneToMany) and only use mappedBy for defining where the owning side of a relationship is (not what the primary key is, JPA can determine that by @Id).

Comment: Good info, I appreciate the help. Ill update once I look over everything

Comment: So you guys are designing a directory that has only directories as children. Perfect..

Comment: @Rob - It could be, it might not be. You've made that assumption yourself. All you know is there is a class named Dir that have a single parent and children. As the Asker is trying to learn JPA, have you considered that could be the point for now?

Comment: Lemme check, um, no. I don't believe in abbreviated variable names, so you are right it might not be a directory. But I bet it is. I also don't believe in the usefulness of learning from broken things. You down voted my answer, mentioning cardinality, which has nothing to do with this question. The title says implement a tree in JPA. That's what Composite is for, assuming the types are different (they are in a file system).

Comment: If it is, or isn't it doesn't matter. Yes the title says implement a tree in JPA, but in the body of the question the asker is struggling with getting relationship mappings to work. (how to declare cardinality of a relationship, what mappedBy means, and how it possible to relate an entity to itself). Yes a Composite Pattern would help one implement a file system and flex things gracefully, if that is indeed the asker's end goal, but it doesn't help if the asker has trouble getting the mappings correct in the first place.

Comment: Your opinion (unfounded). If someone wants to do something, giving them the right way to do it is the best idea. Treating symptoms doesn't teach anything.

Comment: @Rob - If the goal is implement a file system in a database using Java, the right way is to reuse other projects that have already done the same, and not to reinvent the wheel (Apache Jackrabbit comes to mind). Reimplementing should only happen when you have a specific requirement that doesn't fit. Yes my opinion is that the goal of the question is to understand JPA. If the goal were figuring out a better way to implement a file system, I feel the question should be posed in a manner of "I have X pieces, but Y doesn't fit right". Enough with the snide comments.

Comment: @Charlie surprise: no one elected you the moderator of this question. You threw the first snide comment and get to call which one is the last one? My comments aren't snide. The great thing is the record is here. See you 'round.. hopefully people will get help from others on the threads you try to commandeer...

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be the property **mappedBy**, try to remove it. I think you don't need use something like that for your implementation.

```
@Entity
public class Dir {

@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "dirId")
private Integer dirId;

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL )
private Dir parent;

    ....

}
```

Comment: Thanks, giving that a shot now

Comment: I still seem to be getting it when I try to deploy with just @OneToOne

Comment: I have no problems with the class like above, have you put the "@Entity" on **Dir** class?

Answer (score -2):

You should do an implementation of the [Composite Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). Simple to do with JPA:

- Create an abstract base class, e.g. FileSystemItem.
- Create a class called Folder, and one called File that both extend Node.
- Choose an inheritance strategy. For this you could probably use a discriminator and have both types in one file.
- Put the attribute name in the base class.
- Make a collection in the folder class of, not Files, but FileSystemItems.

That's pretty much it. The other big decision is what to do with the add method. If you put it in the base class, you have to throw an unsupported operation exception if someone calls it on a File.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the cardinality of a JPA managed relationship.

Comment: -1 OP asked for a simple mapping for a tree, your answer is VERY misleading for a newbie.